# Why is GDB not displaying this heap address anywhere?

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gdb

I am debugging a program and have the following:

```
(gdb) info proc map
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
            0x400000           0x401000     0x1000        0x0 /home/user/code/c/overread
            0x401000           0x402000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/user/code/c/overread
            0x402000           0x403000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/user/code/c/overread
            0x403000           0x404000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/user/code/c/overread
            0x404000           0x405000     0x1000     0x3000 /home/user/code/c/overread
      0x7f398ba54000     0x7f398ba7a000    0x26000        0x0 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398ba7a000     0x7f398bbc9000   0x14f000    0x26000 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398bbc9000     0x7f398bc14000    0x4b000   0x175000 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc14000     0x7f398bc15000     0x1000   0x1c0000 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc15000     0x7f398bc18000     0x3000   0x1c0000 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc18000     0x7f398bc1b000     0x3000   0x1c3000 /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc41000     0x7f398bc42000     0x1000        0x0 /usr/lib64/ld-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc42000     0x7f398bc63000    0x21000     0x1000 /usr/lib64/ld-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc63000     0x7f398bc6c000     0x9000    0x22000 /usr/lib64/ld-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc6c000     0x7f398bc6d000     0x1000    0x2a000 /usr/lib64/ld-2.32.so
      0x7f398bc6d000     0x7f398bc6f000     0x2000    0x2b000 /usr/lib64/ld-2.32.so
(gdb) p heap_buffer
$10 = 0x12942a0 "BBBBB"
```

I do not know why address `0x12942a0` does not appear anywhere in the process map ranges, yet I can dereference it. Why is this the case?

Reference program (obviously an experimental program to learn about overreads):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    int parsed_argv = atoi(argv[1]);
    char stack_buffer[5] = "AAAAA";
    char *heap_buffer = malloc(6);
    // No NULL check, hehe
    strcpy(heap_buffer, "BBBBB");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < parsed_argv; ++i)
    {
        //putchar(stack_buffer[i]);
        putchar(heap_buffer[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(heap_buffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The heap is not a mapped file.

Comment: Are you running on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It works

This was tested on linux.

`info proc mappings` can indeed reveal the location of the heap. However, you need to advance your code execution after some dynamic allocation first, otherwise the heap region is not assigned to your process.

#### Launch gdb, run your process

> ```
> $ gdb ./a.out
> ...
> (gdb) break main
> ...
> (gdb) run blahblah
> ...
> ```

At this point, when you perform `info proc mappings`, the heap is not present in the table.

#### Advance past the call to `malloc`

> ```
> (gdb) n
> ...
> (gdb) n
> ...
> (gdb) n
> ...
> ```

Now, the heap location will be visible when you perform `info proc mappings`

#### Observe the heap location

> ```
> (gdb) info proc mappings
> ...
>             0x601000           0x622000    0x21000          0                                   [heap]
> ...
> ```

Of course, the location printed by your `gdb` for your process may be different from what is shown for mine.

#### This info is in `/proc`

If you know the process id of your process, you can look in `/proc/<pid>/maps` to find the same info.

> ```
> $ ps
>   PID TTY          TIME CMD
> 21015 pts/62   00:00:00 bash
> 21629 pts/62   00:00:00 gdb
> 21631 pts/62   00:00:00 a.out
> 32825 pts/62   00:00:00 ps
> $ cat /proc/21631/maps | grep heap
> 00601000-00622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a memory mapped view of a binary file (`.so`), it's a pointer to virtual memory your OS gives you for use (through `malloc`).

Comment: I thought this was an entire view of the process' memory layout, but it seems to only be of the mapped portions. Strange, as there are several other answers and threads online, as well as at least 1 school professor who recommends using `info proc mappings` to get the location of the heap: https://samsclass.info/127/proj/ED205c.htm FIND: "Observing the heap"